# set image from server as wallpaper with full size

Tags: android

i'm using these codes to set my image from server as wallpaper :

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
InputStream ins;
try {
String xlx = "http://myserver.com/myimage.jpg";
ins = new URL(xlx).openStream();
wpm.setStream(ins);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it's working and my image will set as wallpaper,
but my problem is that it is not setting full image as wallpaper, so how should i do to set full image as wallpaper without cropping?

Answer (score 0):

set imageview property in your layout xml file.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: my question is not about showing full size in imageview